# One time error - The communication object cannot be used for communication because it has been Aborted

Tags: c#, named-pipes

A WinForms application (server) starts another application (client) and a two-way communication between the two is established using NetNamedPipeBinding.
The service is started using

```
private void StartServiceHost()
{
    NetNamedPipeBinding binding = new NetNamedPipeBinding();
    binding.ReceiveTimeout = new TimeSpan(24, 0, 0);
    binding.SendTimeout = new TimeSpan(24, 0, 0);
    m_ServiceHost = new ServiceHost(typeof(ExnService), new Uri(ExnIPCUtil.ExnServiceBaseAddress));
    m_ServiceHost.AddServiceEndpoint(typeof(IExnService), binding, ExnIPCUtil.ExnServiceEndPointAddress);
    m_ServiceHost.Open();
}
```

And on the client

```
public ExnServiceClient()
{
    var callback = new ExnServiceCallBack();
    var context = new InstanceContext(callback);
    var pipeFactory =
         new DuplexChannelFactory<IExnService>(context,
         new NetNamedPipeBinding(),
         new EndpointAddress(ExnIPCUtil.ExnServiceBaseAddress + "/" + ExnIPCUtil.ExnServiceEndPointAddress));
    ExnService = pipeFactory.CreateChannel();
    ExnService.Connect();
}
```

It works fine but recently in a client’s machine we got the following error

> System.ServiceModel.CommunicationObjectAbortedException: The
>   communication object, System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel,
>   cannot be used for communication because it has been Aborted. Server
>   stack trace:     at
>   System.ServiceModel.Channels.CommunicationObject.ThrowIfDisposedOrNotOpen()
>   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.EnsureOpened(TimeSpan
>   timeout)    at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.Call(String
>   action, Boolean oneway, ProxyOperationRuntime operation, Object[] ins,
>   Object[] outs, TimeSpan timeout)    at
>   System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.InvokeService(IMethodCallMessage
>   methodCall, ProxyOperationRuntime operation)    at
>   System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.Invoke(IMessage
>   message) Exception rethrown at [0]:     at
>   System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.HandleReturnMessage(IMessage
>   reqMsg, IMessage retMsg)    at
>   System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.PrivateInvoke(MessageData&
>   msgData, Int32 type)    at ExnIPC.IExnService.SendMessage(Int32 msgId,
>   String message)

.....application calls

Both server and client apps are on the same machine.
The problem is that up to now it has happened only once and so we cannot determine the steps to re-create it.
I found several posts about the same problem but none relevant to my case so any possible explanation/ideas would be very helpful.

Comment: Is your server code running when you start the client?  check the process using task manager to make sure server to terminate before starting the client.

Comment: server is running and the client is started from the server - it is a one to one relationship.

Comment: Delete cookies from IE history and try again.  The cookie is either corrupted or expired.

Comment: How are cookies interfering with two windows applications (server and client) running on the same machine?

Comment: Does it make a difference if the client and server are on the same machine or different machine.  You are communicating between two different applications.

Comment: In my case it is always in the same machine. Also it only happened once and I am just trying to find out what the cause might have been.

Comment: It sound like you may of hit a timeout.  The PC was hung up doing something else.  Maybe increase the timeout inside the command.  How long was it running before the error occurred?

Comment: Binding Receive + Send timeouts are set to 24h. I was not around but it must have been running for a couple of hours. There were some LAN problems but both applications were running on the same machine.

Comment: It looks like the connection is http and uses a proxy server.  So if there was Lan issues the proxy server may not of been available.

Comment: BaseAddress is "net.pipe://localhost/....." and EndPointAddress is just the name of the service.

Comment: The exception says : System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.HandleReturnMessage